# What would happen to bitcoin in a world with no electricity/internet?

Tags: alternatives, money, offline-transactions

Many people discuss gold as an 'apocalyptic' currency because it will be what's used (supposedly) if the world ends, or there is some cataclysmic event that wipes out the power grid and internet connectivity.

In such a scenario, would bitcoin still maintain value, could a blockchain be maintained, would paper wallets still contain bitcoin, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Without computers or electricity, Bitcoin would have no value and could not be used as it is entirely a digital asset. There are no such an object as a coin and thus Bitcoin cannot be put into a physical asset. The blockchain itself is what determines something is Bitcoin, and without it (because there are no computers or electricity), anything physical intended to represent or store Bitcoin (e.g. a paper wallet) has no value besides the value of the material itself.